# How to get an induction principle for nested fix

Tags: recursion, coq, induction, totality

I am working with a function that searches through a range of values.

```
Require Import List.

(* Implementation of ListTest omitted. *)
Definition ListTest (l : list nat) := false.

Definition SearchCountList n :=
  (fix f i l := match i with
  | 0 => ListTest (rev l)
  | S i1 =>
    (fix g j l1 := match j with
    | 0 => false
    | S j1 =>
      if f i1 (j :: l1)
      then true
      else g j1 l1
    end) (n + n) (i :: l)
  end) n nil
.
```

I want to be able to reason about this function.

However, I can't seem to get coq's built-in induction principle facilities to work.

```
Functional Scheme SearchCountList := Induction for SearchCountList Sort Prop.

Error: GRec not handled
```

It looks like coq is set up for handling mutual recursion, not nested recursion.  In this case, I have essentially 2 nested for loops.

However, translating to mutual recursion isn't so easy either:

```
Definition SearchCountList_Loop :=
  fix outer n i l {struct i} :=
    match i with
    | 0 => ListTest (rev l)
    | S i1 => inner n i1 (n + n) (i :: l)
    end
  with inner n i j l {struct j} :=
    match j with
    | 0 => false
    | S j1 =>
      if outer n i (j :: l)
      then true
      else inner n i j1 l
    end
  for outer
.
```

but that yields the error

> Recursive call to inner has principal argument equal to 
>     "`n + n`" instead of "`i1`".

So, it looks like I would need to use measure to get it to accept the definition directly.  It is confused that I reset j sometimes.  But, in a nested set up, that makes sense, since i has decreased, and i is the outer loop.

So, is there a standard way of handling nested recursion, as opposed to mutual recursion?  Are there easier ways to reason about the cases, not involving making separate induction theorems?  Since I haven't found a way to generate it automatically, I guess I'm stuck with writing the induction principle directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a trick for avoiding mutual recursion in this case: you can compute `f i1` inside `f` and pass the result to `g`.

```
Fixpoint g (f_n_i1 : list nat -> bool) (j : nat) (l1 : list nat) : bool :=
  match j with
  | 0 => false
  | S j1 => if f_n_i1 (j :: l1) then true else g f_n_i1 j1 l1
  end.

Fixpoint f (n i : nat) (l : list nat) : bool :=
  match i with
  | 0 => ListTest (rev l)
  | S i1 => g (f n i1) (n + n) (i :: l)
  end.

Definition SearchCountList (n : nat) : bool := f n n nil.
```

Are you sure simple induction wouldn't have been enough in the original code? What about well founded induction?

Comment: Thanks.  This construction should work.
Flipping it around by turning the captured variables
into curried arguments is a good idea.
Now, I have separate functions, and probably can
just use plain induction without extra fuss.

Ideally I'd want to be able to say something like:
induction n, (SearchCountList n) and have all
of the extra premises and loop invariant, etc.
But, with this hint, I should be able to get there
more easily and directly.